# Stream returning random numbers after reading

Tags: c#, tcp, stream, tcpclient

My `NetworkStream` returns completely random numbers after the first read/write 
here's my code

```
String message = "";
Stream Stream = client.GetStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int read = Stream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
int index = 0;
while (buffer[index] != 0)
{

    message += ((char)buffer[index]);

    index++;
}
Console.WriteLine(message.Trim());
buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Received at:" + DateTime.Now);
Stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Stream.Flush();
Thread.Sleep(300);
Console.WriteLine("Message received at:" + DateTime.Now);
if (message == "")
{
    Run = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Verbinding sluiten");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I very much doubt that it's returning *random* numbers. That's not a good way of converting binary into text anyway, mind you. Please show what you think you're sending and what you're seeing.

Comment: BTW: If you want to echo the the message you should use `Stream.Write(buffer, 0, read);`  *read* may be smaller than *buffer.Length* (same thing is also valid for your while loop)

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. I apparentely tried to send the whole message history over the network stream to the host and that's where the random numbers came from but now it's fixed.